# MVC List Null on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

My Controller populates my Model with a list with `strings` that appear in a `DropDownList` in my View. When the view is posted back to my Controller, that list is suddenly **null**. Why is it null, and what happened to the list of strings I created?

The list was properly populated and shows up in the View. The remainder of the form elements DO properly post back. For example, *`selectedName`* has whatever name the user clicked on. The only thing that is not posting back is *`nameList`*.

Here is the relevant part of my model,

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Selected")]
    public string selectedName{ get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Names")]
    public List<string> nameList{ get; set; }
}
```

the relevant Get and Post parts of my Controller,

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> nameList= getNames();
        MyModel model = new MyModel()
        model.nameList= nameList;
        // Now, model.nameList has a bunch of stuff in it
        return View(model); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        if(model.nameList== null)
        {
            cry();
            postOnStackOverflow();
        }
        return View(model); 
    }
}
```

and the relevant part of my View (which is encapsulated inside of a form).

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.nameList):
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.selectedName, new SelectList(Model.nameList), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
</p>
```

Comment: I couldn't see a `names` property in your model

Comment: @Selman22 Sorry, that's a typo. I changed a lot of variable names to stay in line with my work's policies. Correcting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the value of the drop down list is posted when you post the form.  I assume that your control in question is on a form.

I am not sure why you want to always return to the view you posted from, but you need to repopulate the list:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
         List<string> names = getNames();

        model.nameList = names;
        return View(model); 
    }
```

Comment: An alternative would be to make the list of names a member of the model. Then there would be no need to remember to repopulate it.

Comment: Its already a member, but its not posted back as it isn't held in the value of any control on the form.

Comment: I was unclear - sorry - I meant to make the method that builds the list a member of the model, and have the model build the list itself, either in the getter for the list, or in a constructor or something.

Comment: The list IS part of my model. I don't want to rebuild the list when I get back. I already built it once. I don't want to build it again. However, please don't downvote this answer because there was a typo in my question that may have confused the author.

Comment: That's not how model binding works.  The list would need to be the value of a control that is part of the form, otherwise its not part of the post.

Comment: Are you saying that it is impossible to post back a list of values. If there is a way to post the entire list, rather than null, then that is the answer I seek.

Comment: Without creating a custom model binder, there isn't a good way to do this, no.

Comment: I upvoted this answer since it provides a simple and clear solution to your problem, but having the model take care of the building of the list by, giving it a read-only property which returns the list for example, would in my opinion provide a better separation of concerns. But others would argue otherwise, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour considering what you have in your view. You need to reload the namelist collection property incase you are returning model to the same view again.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     // Save and redirect
   }
   //reload the collection again and return the model to the view
   model.nameList=getNames();
   return View(model); 
}
```

Comment: Rebuilding the entire list on every postback does not seem very efficient. I read my list of names from an XML file, which is expensive. I already built the list once, and I want to avoid building it again. My question was "What happened to the list of names I already created?"

Comment: Unless it is not in stored in a form element, It won't be available. You may cache the data you read from XML file and use that to reload.